# Symfony2 Doctrine Query, only populate single field in OneToMany Relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to only populate a single field in a QueryBuilder query that fetches the relationship, my case:

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT s FROM IREnterpriseAppBundle:StockItem s
    WHERE s.user = :currentUser AND s.deleted = 0
    ORDER BY s.id DESC'
)->setParameters(array('currentUser' => $user));
```

Now the entity StockItem has a relationship to the user:

```
/**
 * StockItem
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="IREnterprise\AppBundle\Entity\StockItemRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 *
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 *
 */
class StockItem
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @Expose
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="IREnterprise\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="stockItems")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @Expose
     **/
    private $user;
}
```

On the aforementioned query, the entire User object is fetched alongside with the stockitem, is it possible to only fetch/set a single field on the user object?

Since i am having issues excluding the rest of the user object with @exclusion policy: [JMSSerializerbundle @expose relationship, ignores other entities policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373667/jmsserializerbundle-expose-relationship-ignores-other-entities-policies)

As a last resort i have to unset the fields of the user object in code, but that just seems retarded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to *only* fetch a single field from a related entity but doing so, you won't be able to persist any change to the result.

If that's ok with you, you should use a `JOIN` and specify which fields from the related entity you want to fetch.

As mentioned in another answer, you can use `createQueryBuilder` instead of `createQuery`.

**`createQueryBuilder` code sample:**

```
$result = $em->getRepository('IREnterpriseAppBundle:StockItem')
    ->createQueryBuilder('s')
    ->select('s.id, u.id as user_id')
    ->join('s.user', 'u')
    ->where('s.user = :currentUser')
    ->andWhere('s.deleted = 0')
    ->setParameter('currentUser', $user)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

**`createQuery` code sample:**

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT s.id, u.id as user_id FROM IREnterpriseAppBundle:StockItem s
    JOIN s.user u
    WHERE s.user = :currentUser AND s.deleted = 0
    ORDER BY s.id DESC'
)->setParameters(array('currentUser' => $user));
```